Azure Loadbalancer with public IP forward traffic to Container Apps
We have deployed a azurerm_container_app_environment and a azurerm_container_app using terraform.
resource "azurerm_container_app_environment" "myenv" {
    name                     = var.managed_environment_name
    location                 ...
    ...
    infrastructure_subnet_id       = var.infrastructure_subnet_id
    internal_load_balancer_enabled = true
    ...
    workload_profile { 
      name                  = "Consumption"
      workload_profile_type = "Consumption"
      ...
   }
}

resource "azurerm_container_app" "myapp" {
    name           = "myapp"
    revision_mode  = "Single"
    ...    
    ingress {
      external_enabled           = true
      target_port                = 80
      exposed_port               = 8000
      transport                  = "tcp"    
   }
   ....
}

I can curl my container app using the private ip assigned to the env without issues:
curl -kvvv http://XXX.XXX.XXX:8000

We also have a azurerm_public_ip and azurerm_lb
Now we would like to expose the traffic from the container app to the public IP
So we configured the LB in this way
 resource "azurerm_lb_probe" "probe" {
      loadbalancer_id = var.load_balancer_id
      name            = "probe"
      port            = 8000
      protocol        = "Tcp" 
      ....
}

resource "azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool" "pool" {
     loadbalancer_id = var.load_balancer_id
     name            = "BackEndAddressPool"
}

resource "azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool_address" "address_pool" {
     name                    = "address_pool"
     backend_address_pool_id = azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool.pool.id
     virtual_network_id      = var.vnet_id
     ip_address              = azurerm_container_app_environment.myapp.static_ip_address

}
resource "azurerm_lb_rule" "lb_rule" {
      loadbalancer_id     = var.load_balancer_id
      name                = "lb-rule"
      protocol            = "Tcp"
      frontend_port       = 80
      backend_port        = 8000
      backend_address_pool_ids = [azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool.pool.id]
      probe_id                 = azurerm_lb_probe.probe.id
     ....

}
The issue is that apparently it's not working. The Lb metrics "Health Probe status" is always 0

have you check with nsg that allows port 8000 ? @fabry is this configured to allow?

@VinayB yes I tried to set the NSG as well but it didn't work

Are you using internal Container apps or external one?

The Azure Load Balancer is meant to work only for Backend VMs
